# component interactions not working in angular

Tags: angular

I'm studying component interactions in angular. I tried importing everything needed and followed the steps that were told, but its not working. I am not getting any error either in the console.

PARENT COMPONENT: APP COMPONENT

1. app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: `

          `,
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'arpitz';
    public name ="Arpit"
    public message = ""
}
```

2. app.component.html:

```
<h1>welcome {{message}}</h1>
<app-forms (childEvent)="message=$event" [parentData]="name"></app-forms>
```

3. CHILD COMPONENT: FORMS COMPONENT

forms.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
      selector: 'app-forms',
      template:`
      <h2>{{"hello" + parentData}}</h2>
      <button onclick="fireEvent()">/<button>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public parentData
    @Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter()
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
    fireEvent(){
      this.childEvent.emit('hi from child component')
    }
}
```

just in case you were wondering about the app module, here's that too:
app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PractiseComponent } from './myComponents/practise/practise.component';
import { Practise2Component } from './myComponents/practise2/practise2.component';
import { FormsComponent } from './myComponents/forms/forms.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PractiseComponent,
    Practise2Component,
    FormsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `templateUrl` instead of `template`, or inline the HTML in app component's `template`:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html', //may change depending on the dirs,
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Or:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: `
       <h1>welcome {{message}}</h1>
       <app-forms (childEvent)="message=$event" [parentData]="name"></app-forms>`
    ,
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your code is binding of **click** event is wrong.
Here is my code of **binding click event** in angular.

```
 <button (click)="fireEvent()">/<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the Answers provided above.

You had an error because there was nothing in your HTML template. you opted for in-line template but you did not add contents to it.

**page: app.component.ts**

this

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: ``, // NOTE HERE
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
    title = 'arpitz';
    public name ="Arpit"
    public message = ""
  }
```

Should be changed to this:

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html', // NOTE HERE
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
    title = 'arpitz';
    public name ="Arpit"
    public message = ""
  }
```

This makes use of the External template [Read More about Angular Component metadata Here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#component-metadata).

You can also choose to make it an inline HTML

```
       import { Component } from '@angular/core';
       @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       template: `
          <h1>welcome {{message}}</h1>
           <app-forms (childEvent)="message=$event" [parentData]="name"></app-forms>
       `, // NOTE HERE
       styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
       })
       export class AppComponent {
        title = 'arpitz';
        public name ="Arpit"
        public message = ""
      }
```

**page: forms.component.ts**

Make use of *(click)* instead of *onclick*
[Read more on Angular event binding here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
      selector: 'app-forms',
      template:`
      <h2>{{"hello" + parentData}}</h2>
      <button (click)="fireEvent()">/<button>  // NOTE HERE
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public parentData
    @Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter()
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
    fireEvent(){
      this.childEvent.emit('hi from child component')
    }
}
```

All the best in your Angular knowledge pursuit